# Reloading CloudKit data when app comes to foreground

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, cloudkit

I'm trying to understand CloudKit, but I'm having an issue figuring out a real-world issue if I eventually turned it into an app.

I've got a tableviewcontroller that's populated by CloudKit, which works fine.  I've got a detailviewcontroller that is pushed when you tap one of the entries in the tableview controller.  The detailviewcontroller pulls additional data from CloudKit that wasn't in the initial tableviewcontroller. All of this works perfectly fine.

Now, the detailviewcontroller allows changing of an image and saving it back to a public database.  That's working fine as well.

The scenario I'm dealing with is thinking about this core function being used in an app by multiple people.  If one person uploads a photo (overwriting an existing photo for one of the records), what happens if another user currently has the app in the background?  If they open the app, they'll see the last photo they saw on that page, and not the new photo.  So I want to reload the data from CloudKit when the app comes back to the foreground, but I must be doing something wrong, because it's not working.  Using the simulator and my actual phone, I can change a photo on one device and the other device (simulator or phone) doesn't update the data when it comes into the foreground.

Here's the code I'm using:  First in ViewController.swift:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    println("viewDidLoad")

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "activeAgain", name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
```

and then the activeAgain function:

```
    func activeAgain() {

    println("Active again")
    fetchItems()
    self.tblItems.reloadData()
    println("Table reloaded") 
}
```

and then the fetchItems function:

```
    func fetchItems() {
    let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    let publicDatabase = container.publicCloudDatabase
    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)

    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Items", predicate: predicate)

    publicDatabase.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { (results, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            println(error)
        }
        else {
            println(results)

            for result in results {
                self.items.append(result as! CKRecord)
            }

            NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
                self.tblItems.reloadData()
                self.tblItems.hidden = false
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I tried adding a reload function to viewWillAppear, but that didn't really help:

```
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    tblItems.reloadData()
}
```

Now here's the code in DetailViewController.swift:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "activeAgain", name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)

    self.imageScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1000, 1000)
    self.imageScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1000, 1000)
    self.imageScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    self.pinBoardScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 8.0

    showImage()
```

and then the showImage function:

```
    func showImage() {

    imageView.hidden = true
    btnRemoveImage.hidden = true
    viewWait.hidden = true

    if let editedImage = editedImageRecord {

        if let imageAsset: CKAsset = editedImage.valueForKey("image") as? CKAsset {

            imageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageAsset.fileURL.path!)

            imageURL = imageAsset.fileURL

            self.title = "Image"

            imageView.hidden = false
            btnRemoveImage.hidden = false
            btnSelectPhoto.hidden = true

        }
    }

}
```

and the activeAgain function:

```
    func activeAgain() {
    showImage()
    println("Active again")
}
```

Neither of these ViewControllers reload the data from CloudKit when they return.  It's like it's cached the table data for the first ViewController and the image for the DetailViewController and it's using that instead of downloading the actual CloudKit data.  I'm stumped, so I figure I better try this forum (my first post!).  Hopefully I included enough required info to be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your showImage function is using a editedImage CKRecord. Did you also reload that record? Otherwise the Image field in that record would then still contain the old CKAsset.

Besides just reloading on a moment you feel right, you could also let the changes be pushed by creating a CloudKit subscription. Then your data will even change when it's active and changed by someone else.

Comment: I just starting reading about subscriptions yesterday.  I think you're right, the subscription idea seems the best way.  Now I have to find some subscription examples in Swift so I can understand how they work.  Thanks for your help!